# Disable iPhone haptics without disabling Vibrate on Silent

Tags: iphone, ios, haptic-feedback

I want the phone to vibrate when the ring is silenced. I have Vibrate on Silent enabled and System Haptics disabled.

- If **Accessibility** > **Touch** > **Vibration** is enabled, the phone still vibrates when I touch the screen for more than a fraction of a second.
- If **Accessibility** > **Touch** > **Vibration** is disabled, the phone does not vibrate when calls come in.

How can I disable all system vibrations, but have the phone still vibrate for incoming calls and alarms?